# Connect by prior with condition

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I need to write a hierarchical query with condition I.e. If the condition is true certain columns should be used in connect by prior clause and if it's false, some other columns should be in the clause.

Pseudo code
...

```
If col1 is not null then
  Connect by prior col1=col1
Else
  Connect by prior col2=col2 
...
```

Is something like this possible in plsql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to encapsulate the conditions properly:

```
connect by (col1 is not null and prior col1=col1)
  or (col1 is null and prior col2=col2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
CONNECT BY PRIOR CASE WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL THEN col1 ELSE col2 END
               = CASE WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL THEN col1 ELSE col2 END
```

Comment: i´ll just add that without the `prior` you might aswell land in an infinite select here? (not really sure though)